# How to access Internal Phone Databases in a Cordova App

Tags: android, html, cordova, plugins, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a mobile application in Visual Studio 2015 with the tools for Apache Cordova.

How can I access internal phone databases like the call log in this type of an application?  I have been able to access the contact list by downloading a Git Plugin but i can't find any plugin to access the recent call log and i would like to know if there's a better plugin that works for a call log or if there's a way to access phone databases with existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this plugin that seems to help with what you are looking for: https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin however it is currently only supported on Android. I do not personally think that something like this would be possible on iOS due to its security measures. I could be wrong but I wouldn't bet on it happening.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did look into that and the usage of that plugin looks like its designed mainly for AngularJS usage.  If you have any suggestions as to how to implement the documentation of this plugin into an HTML/CSS/JS Cordova project i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Only the example usage is for an angular application. If you look at the actual code at https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin/blob/master/www/CallLog.js you'll be able to see the functions that you can call in a normal cordova project